# Script doesn't work after changing scene or closing Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got the problem that title suggests.
I' ve got some door gameobjects to which I attached the following script in order to open and close them by raycast:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
        {
            if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())   
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "door")
                {                     
                   if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().GetBool("ApritiSesamo") == true)
                    {
                        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("ApritiSesamo", false);
                    }
                    else if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().GetBool("ApritiSesamo") == false)
                    {
                        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("ApritiSesamo", true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The object has the "door" tag and in the animator I've got a transition from `Entry-->New state(an empty one)--->my door animation`. In the animator, the transition arrows respectively need the `bool ApritiSesamo` to become `true` to execute the "open door animation"... and `false` to return to the empty state.

The problem is that this all works until I close unity or change scene (and come back in this scene to try again).Also, I noticed that if i copy paste this door gameObject...the original one still no works but the copy works until I close Unity or change scene ecc.

Hope I explained all clearly and hope to recive some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I correct myself. If I copy paste a door gameobject which is not working, all the others and the copied one in the scene work correctly too.

Comment: Is your script still attached to the objects when you reopen the scene, or is the script component missing?

Comment: Yes, if i click on the game object I can still see the script.

Comment: By the way my problem has changed a bit. I got the door on both scene 1 and scene 2. On scene 1, when i hit play, it works perfectly. Then i pass to the second level(scene 2) and here it no works at all. On the main camera there is the dontdestroyonload(...) so that it passes from scene 1 to scene 2 after level load. Thanks in advance for help, if you want I can make a video and send you on whatsapp.